# Cannot find LDAP group with special characters

Tags: vb.net, ldap

Using `accountmanagement` I am able to check to see if a group exists, by using the following..

```
Dim groupName = "ALL HB/LKM Engineering"
Using context = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com")
   Dim groupPrincipal__1 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 
   IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName)
   Dim GroupExists As Boolean = (groupPrincipal__1 IsNot Nothing)
   MessageBox.Show(GroupExists)
End Using
```

I know the group exists, but it tells me it doesn't. This code also works on every other test, but groups with / in it, it returns false... even though I KNOW it exists.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Changing the group names, isn't a current option.

Comment: Did you try "ALL HB\/LKM Engineering"?

Comment: Yep, it doesn't find it. I can list all groups with groupprincipal, and it finds them... it's odd.